# How to construct a URI for running an executable JAR to run on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jersey, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Jersey and an embedded container (in my case Jdk HTTP). How do I configure the Uri string appropriately to run on an arbitrary server listening to the appropriate port?

```
public class App {
    static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // runs locally
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(8080).build();

        ResourceConfig config = ResourceConfig(MyStuff.class);
        HttpServer server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, config);

        log.info("App started at ${uri.host}:${uri.port}. Press <enter> to terminate.")

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        reader.read();
        server.stop(0);
    }
}
```

I'm deploying to AWS ElasticBeanstalk by creating their default starter ElasticBeanstalk instance.

1) Is there a way to configure my URI so that it will work on EB and locally?
2) If not, what is the correct configuration for running on EB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using default settings, `http://localhost:5000/` is the correct URI/port to run a standalone Java app on Elastic Beanstalk. EB instances have an nginx proxy on each instance that takes HTTP requests and hands them off to the Java server on port 5000.

Correct code to run on AWS below. Port 5000 is the default but can be overridden:

```
URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(5000).build();
```